# number of inferred invalid tuples by existing constraints

Tags: python, c++, constraints, constraint-programming, pulp

I have been dealing with this problem for days but still no solution. Let me explain it on a simple example.

Assume there is an array of integers with length 8. Every cell can take certain values. First 4 cells can take 0 or 1 and the other half can take 0, 1 or 2. These 3 arrays can be some examples.

```
{1,1,0,1,2,1,0,2}
{1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2}
{0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1}
```

However there are some constraints to construct the arrays as follows:

```
constraint1 = {0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-}  // !(constraint1[0]==0 && constraint1[1]==0) 
constraint2 = {-,1,0,-,-,-,-,-}  // !(constraint2[1]==1 && constraint2[2]==0) 
constraint3 = {-,-,-,-,1,1,-,0}  // !(constraint3[4]==1 && constraint3[5]==1 && constraint3[7]==0)
```

For better understanding;

```
{0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0}  // this is not valid, because it violates the constraint2
{0,0,2,2,1,1,0,1}  // this is not valid, because it violates the constraint1
{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}  // this is valid, because it violates none of the constraints
```

The question is that I need to find the **number** of inferred t-tuples (t-length) from these constraints. For example, assume that one of the generated array which does not violate any of the constraints is called `myArray`. If you look at `constraint1`,  it indicates that if `myArray[0]` is 0, no matter what `myArray[1]` has to be 1. Because `myArray[1]` can take only 0 and 1 and if it gets 0, then it will violate the `constraint1`. Hence;

```
myArray[0]=0 => myArray[1]=1
```

Now if we look at the `constraint2` , it says that if `myArray[1]` is 1 then `myArray[2]` can not be 0. Since in our case we already choose that `myArray[1]` is 1, `myArray[2]` will be 0.

```
myArray[1]=1 => myArray[2]=0
```

When these implications are combined, one more constraint is formed as;

```
myArray[0]=0 => myArray[1]=1 => myArray[2]=0
myArray[0]=0 => myArray[2]=0  // new constraint
{2,-,0,-,-,-,-,-}
```

I want to strictly emphasize that this is a very simple example only to illustrate you the problem. In my case, the length of the arrays are changing between 50-200. Number constraints can be anything between 0 and 500 (maybe even more). I also want to emphasize that all I need is **number** of the inferred constraints, no need to find them.

Here are some approaches that I have tried;

1) Find the truth table of the options for constraints those have same at least one common option. Then, look for all t-tuples. It turned out that the space is very big.

2) Find all the solution which does not violates constraints in mathematica (satisfiable problem), then look for which t-tuples are missing. It can not find even one solution.

The problem is that in these approaches I have tried to generate whole space which I do not need. Is there any better ideas to find number of t-tuples (constraints) without enumerating whole space?

Comment: Doesn't your third example violate both constraint 2 and 3? Did you mean `[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]`? By the way, when talking about Python you may want to use Python's list syntax, curly brackets are used for sets.

Comment: Never mind, had it the wrong way round...